# How does cartesian product join transfer data internally for join in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have 2 types of nested loop join in spark
Broadcast nested loop join,
Shuffle replicate nested loop join(cartesian)

I know that in the broadcast one , the smaller table is broadcasted to all the nodes for the join.

I am not sure what happens in cartesian join.
Say we have 2 Dataframes A and B. Then each partition of A need all the partition of B for the join. So in a way B will need to be replicated in all the nodes where partition  of A is present. Does it not make it same as B being broadcasted?
Please correct my understanding.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will have a go. I encourage edits to improve the answer if needed.

Cartesian (cross) join is a shuffle join. a shuffle is best defined as a computational realignment that results into inter/intra executor core communication or data share. Shuffle joins results into worker nodes and potentially every executor core communicating with one another during the entire join process. They are damn expensive because the network can easily give in courtesy of the traffic congestion caused by excessive communication between the worker nodes.

**Note** broadcast does not occur. The driver using partition properties at its disposal reads each df and distributes the data to the worker nodes.

To demonstrate there is no broadcast, lets cross join 2 dfs with 100000000 rows and review the DAG. In this case, the join keys in the2 dfs had string values and white spaces too. In this case I have a worker node with 2 cores

[image]

The two dfs are read into executor. The join keys are parallelly partitioned. These join keys are not returned to the driver. Each executor core holds the partitions in memory and stores them as shuffle files.

Next the cartesian product occurs. Partitions output above are combined before new partitions are computed.

Because this is happening within one executor core residing on a worker node, there is no further data exchange. Consequently, the partitions are zipped, and the join happens. The result is forwarded to the driver, the driver communicates the result to your application and its displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The DAG you showed above looks  similar to  shuffle sort merge join. Are you sure it is cartesian product join? I think DAG for cartesian product should look something like the below 
https://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Cartesian-product-join-Spark-stages.png